# SimpleDateFormat returning null but can print date on screen

Tags: java, date

I have a bit of a dilemma. I have a method that's supposed to convert a given string to the type Date. For some reason I can print out the Date on the screen however the parser returns null when I try to retreive the date from the method.

An example string that is used as the parameter: Thu Aug 10 07:23:00 EEST 2017

```
public Date convertStringToDate(String sDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(sDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: You have two `date` variables...

Comment: @assylias Well, no, he has only one. The other one is called `sDate` and since OP said he got `null` instead of a compiler error for `return date;`, he failed to provide code which actually represents his issue. -1 for that.

Comment: correction...*she. And there is no compiler error that is being given to me. When I print out date, its the exact Date type and value I want. The problem is when I call this method from a different method and assign it to a Date value, I get null.

Comment: @neziy As said above, you have another date variable somewhere in that class or a superclass - but you haven't provided the complete code so it's hard to help you further.

Comment: Alright that's what seemed to be the problem. I was just so focused on why it kept returning null that I didnt even realize I had declared the same date variable somewhere outside of that method. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a second variable named `date` in your `try` body. Remove the `Date` portion (which makes it local). Change

```
Date date = format.parse(sDate);
```

to

```
date = format.parse(sDate);
```

Comment: Where is the first date variable ?

Comment: I had a date variable outside this method.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP.)*

I had declared the date variable somewhere outside the method and to solve this problem I had to declare a local one. Down below is the updated working code:

```
public Date convertStringToDate(String sDate) {
    Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        date = format.parse(sDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```